# How to get a generated Event to appear in the Invitee's Activity History

Tags: apex, event

The user can select a group of `Contacts`.  At that point we create a single new `Event`, as well as, an `EventRelation` for each `Contact` (marked as an `Invitee`)

That is done through a controller extension (see code below) and seems to generate all the objects perfectly.  The problem is I don't know why the `Event` doesn't show up in the 'Activity History for the `Invitee`.

We have 'shared activities' enabled for the organization and no errors or issues appear in the log.

---

```
public with sharing class CreateEvent_Controller
{
    public Event eventNew {get; set;} 
    public List<Contact> selectedContacts { get; set; }  

    public CreateEvent_Controller(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) 
    {
        selectedContacts = [select id, Name from Contact where id IN :((List<Contact>)controller.getSelected())];
        eventNew = new Event();
        eventNew.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(); //Assigned To
        eventNew.GroupEventType = 2;
        eventNew.IsAllDayEvent = true;
        eventNew.IsGroupEvent = true;

        if(selectedContacts.isEmpty() == true)
        {
            ApexPages.Message noContactsSelected = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'No Contact Records Selected: Press The Cancel Button To Return To The Contacts Page To Select Contacts');
            ApexPages.addMessage(noContactsSelected);
        }

    }

    public PageReference SaveEvent() 
    {                       
        Database.saveresult eventInsertResult = database.insert(eventNew); 
        if(eventInsertResult.isSuccess())
        {
            List<EventRelation> contactEventLinks = new List<EventRelation>();

            for(Contact ct: selectedContacts)
            {
                EventRelation newLink = new EventRelation(EventId=eventNew.ID, RelationId=ct.ID, Status='Accepted', IsInvitee=true);
                contactEventLinks.add(newLink);
            }

            if (contactEventLinks.size() > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    insert contactEventLinks;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    delete eventNew;
                }
            }
        }

        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(' HIDDEN FOR DEMO ');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;          
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 properties of `EventRelation` that need to be set correctly for the `Event` to appear in the `Activity History` of each `Invitee`.

- IsInvitee = true - Needed to have the `Contact` automatically accept the `Event`
- IsParent = true - Needed to correctly appear in the `Activity History`
- IsWhat = false - Needed to correctly appear in the `Activity History`